# Problem referencing executable using MATLAB "dos" function

Tags: matlab, dos

I have a fairly simple question that has me stymied. I am trying to run an executable built from a simple C program using MATLAB as a shell, i.e. using the following MATLAB code:

```
FileName = ['D:\Users\person\Desktop\MATLAB\GUI','\Program.exe &'];

dos(FileName);
```

The executable correctly begins running, but crashes giving the error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: D:\Users\person\Desktop\MATLAB\GUI\Program.exe

File: f:\\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\fscanf.c

Expression: (stream != NULL)
```

The programs opens a text file, reads the input, performs math functions, and writes outputs back to another text file.  I assume that this error means there is a problem reading from the text file, BUT-- when I run the executable by itself (i.e. Windows Explorer doubleclick), it executes flawlessly, as I would expect.

So, it's only MATLAB pointing to the file location that is causing the crash.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like relative paths are the culprit.  The Matlab command is running from whatever directory you've specified within Matlab; cmd runs from root or something like that (don't know much about Dos).  That's why it works when you specify absolute paths.  Change your Matlab directory to DOS root, and see if it works as originally coded.

Edit: Note that it's the path to whatever file Program.exe is trying to read that's the problem, not the path to Program.exe itself.

Comment: OP's definition of `fileName` seemed to be absolute paths... still it's entirely a possible source of error.

Comment: @yoda That was the path for the program.  The error arises when Program.exe attempts to read some other file, via fscanf.

Comment: It was a problem with the generation of my C executable.  Fixed it, thanks for your input all!